# Kubernetes deployment does not grab recreated service account token

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes deployment that uses a service account. When I delete and re-create the service account, the pods in the deployment start throwing an error saying:

```
the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
```

My question is, in the case that the service account is deleted, then re-created, how do I ensure that the pods can still authenticate with kubernetes using that service account without having to re-create that deployment?

Comment: Hello @Sam Reynolds, Feel free to update the status of the question.Let me know the answer below helps to resolve your issue? I am happy to help you if you have any further queries.

Comment: Hello @Sam Reynolds, Please check the edit in my answer and below comment, which may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: Sorry, I got caught up in another issue, I'll try out your solution as soon as I get a chance

Comment: Did you had time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If yes, Please consider accepting and upvote it for the greater visibility of the community.

Answer (score 0):

You recreated a service account for your pod, but it is considered a default service account. To change that use kubernetes **RBAC** mode to regulate access to network resources based on the roles of individual users within an enterprise. This helps to create a new RBAC Role or ClusterRole and then uses RoleBinding to bind a role with your new ServiceAccount.

As per the official kubernetes [Authorization Modes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#authorization-modules) documents:

> When specified, RBAC (Role-Based Access Control) uses the
> `rbac.authorization.k8s.io` API group to drive authorization
> decisions, allowing admins to dynamically configure permission
> policies through the Kubernetes API.
>
> To enable RBAC, start the apiserver with `--authorization-mode=RBAC`.
> For example :
>
> ```
> kube-apiserver --authorization-mode=Example,RBAC --other-options --more-options
> ```

**You need to pass that service account name as the value for `ServiceAccountName` key in a `spec` section of your deployment definition file. For example;**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx1
  labels:
    app: nginx1
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx1
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: xxxxx-serviceaccount
      containers:
      - name: nginx1
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Refer to Dawid Ziolkowski’s Loft Blog on [Kubernetes Service Account: What It Is and How to Use It](https://loft.sh/blog/kubernetes-service-account-what-it-is-and-how-to-use-it/) and Bhavyasree’s [Kubernetes-CKAD](https://bhavyasree.github.io/kubernetes-CKAD/12.service-account/) for more information.

**EDIT :**

> You can [opt out of automounting API](https://You%20can%20opt%20out%20of%20automounting%20API%20credentials%20on%20/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token%20for%20a%20service%20account%20by%20setting%20automountServiceAccountToken:%20false%20on%20the%20ServiceAccount:) credentials on
> `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token` for a service
> account by setting `automountServiceAccountToken: false` on the
> ServiceAccount:

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing, but my problem is when I delete the service account that I'm using in my deployment, then re-create , then the running pods in that deployment can no longer be used to authenticate with kubernetes. I'm assuming because the token is no longer valid, so I either need a way to refresh the token or mount the service account token dynamically somehow.

Comment: Can you provide the complete logs,I mean share logs during a failed authentication event?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Refer to [Launch a Pod using service account token projection](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#launch-a-pod-using-service-account-token-projection)
and also check the edit in the answer for **opt out of automounting API**, which may help to resolve your issue.